# How to split CamelCase variable names on case change

Tags: split, sas

How do I split a [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) variable name in the output?

According to this [SAS Blog article](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sastraining/2011/02/23/top-5-sas-programming-best-practices/),

> When you print data, [CamelCase] variable names are automatically split in
>   your output at the next uppercase letter. (Note: this depends on the
>   length of the data field.)

However, when I try

```
data test1;
  input ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits $;
  datalines;
Hello,
World!
;
run;

proc print data = test1;
run;
```

the variable name does not split.

The article does say that splitting depends on the length of the data field.  However, if I modify my data set,

```
data test2;
  length ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits $ 250;
  input ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits $ &;
  datalines;
Hello, World! It's been a long time since we last saw one another. It was nice knowing you. Goodbye, cruel world!
;
run;

proc print data = test2;
run;
```

the result is the same.

The [SAS Community Wiki](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/CamelCase) states

> If the
>   ODS system ever has to split a name over two or more lines to stack
>   the column heading for a more pleasing vertical layout, she will
>   prefer to split at a caseTransition, and so your multi word variable
>   names have a better chance of splitting at "pleasing" boundaries.

So, I try outputting it to a .rtf.

```
ods rtf file = "C:\Users\&SYSUSERID\Documents\tests.rtf";
proc print data = test1;
run;
proc print data = test2;
run;
ods rtf close;
```

Nothing. (Except a warning regarding the data itself and not the variable name.)  The variable name remains unsplit.

```
WARNING: Data too long for column "ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits"; truncated to 98 characters to fit.
```

I would call jiggery-pokery if the claims weren't coming from such reputable sources.  Is there an option or something I'm missing?

Comment: It's a pretty good source but it is community driven so less guarantee about the accuracy of the content. It's more open source style :) I can't find anything to validate this. If you post it at communities.sas.com a SAS developer can answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to work for HTML output (the default in 9.3) but it DOES work for listing output, which is probably what those community sources are referring to.

Try the following:

```
ods html close;
ods listing;
data test2;
  length ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits
    ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits2
    ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits3
    ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits4
      $ 250;
  input ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits $ &;
  ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits2=ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits;
    ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits3=ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits;
    ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits4=ThisIsALongNameThatIHopeSplits;
  datalines;
Goodbye, cruel world!
;
run;

proc print data = test2;
run;
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  What this demonstrates is that SAS has the capability to split along case transitions.  Might it be possible to construct a style template which splits along case transitions?

Comment: for sure, anything is possible with HTML output, although it can be tricky to do that via the ODS system.  You may be better off rendering your HTML directly (eg via data step) if you need that level of control.